# VS Code - How to hide inline warning messages?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Code, how can I hide the inline warning messages inside a file as highlighted below with white circles?

[image: inline messages]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're using the [**Error Lens**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.errorlens) Extension

You can uninstall it completely, or disable messages in settings like this:

```js
"errorLens.messageEnabled": false
```